# How to pop a second value in session?

Tags: python, flask

I have two sessions on my login system, 'admin' and 'standard', I'm popping 'admin' off the session stack when I click logout, I'm wondering how I'd pop the standard session?

```
# Logout of System
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('is_admin')
    #session.pop('standard')
    return render_template('/index.html')
```

Another variation I tried, which does not work

```
# Logout of System
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    if 'is_admin' in session:
        session.pop('is_admin')
    return render_template('/index.html')
    if 'is_standard' in session:
        session.pop('standard')
    return render_template('/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a one-liner:

```
>>> s = {'is_admin': 1, 'standard': 1}
>>> [s.pop(i, None) for i in ['is_admin', 'standard']]
[1, 1]
>>> s
{}
```

> pop(key[, default])
>
> If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else
>   return default. If default is not given and key is not in the
>   dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

Comment: Yep. That is a really concise and terse way to do it. Very pythonic, but a bit unreadable for noobs ;-) You still get my upvote!

Comment: The downside here is that you allocate the memory for the list created by the comprehension that is immediately discarded. A simple for loop would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    for s in ['is_admin', 'standard']:
        try:
            session.pop(s)
        except KeyError:
            continue
    return render_template('/index.html')
```

The above will pop both keys if they exist, or only the one which is there.
This is how your route will look like if you incorporate the list comprehension from sobolevn's answer

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    [session.pop(i, None) for i in ['is_admin', 'standard']]
    return render_template('/index.html')
```

You second variant should be:

```
# Logout of System
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    if 'is_admin' in session:
        session.pop('is_admin')
        return render_template('/index.html')
    if 'is_standard' in session:
        session.pop('standard')
        return render_template('/index.html')
```

It will perform slower than my variant, and it is more verbose.

`Session` in flask is a [wrapper around dictionary](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#sessions). Here is why you can't iterate over session, and remove elements from it:

```
In [35]: session =  {'std': 'bar', 'admin':'foo', 'manager': 'baz'}

In [36]: for s in session:
    try:
        session.pop(s)
    except KeyError:
        continue
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-14e9c7f174be> in <module>()
----> 1 for s in session:
      2     try:
      3         session.pop(s)
      4     except KeyError:
      5         continue

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

This is showing you how it works for both keys:

```
In [37]: session =  {'std': 'bar', 'admin':'foo', 'manager': 'baz'}

In [38]: for s in ['std', 'admin']:
    try:
        session.pop(s)
    except KeyError:
        continue
   ....:     

In [39]: print session
{'manager': 'baz'}
```

And after session is modified, here what you will get:

```
In [41]: for s in ['std', 'admin']:
    try:
        session.pop(s)
    except KeyError:
        print "I didn't find %s" % s
        continue
   ....:     
I didn't find std
I didn't find admin
```

I hope this makes my answer clear.

Comment: I take it I replace for s in [...] to for s in session: ?

Comment: No. You don't. It will iterate on everything in your session. You just wanted to check for two items right?

Comment: What happens if there is only one value in session? when we supply 2 to the loop?

Comment: I already wrote that, if only one exists, it will throw a `KeyError`, and go to the second one, or finish.